# Is this singleton example legal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, instantiation

Adapted the example from [this link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html). Not sure what's wrong with invoking `Logger.create.id`, or shall I invoke `l = Logger.new` first?

```
class Logger
  private_class_method :new
  @@logger = nil

  def Logger.create
    @@logger = new unless @@logger
    @@logger
  end
end

Logger.create.id
```

Comment: I think you may not want to use @@ because that will create global variables.  Don't you want to use one @ symbol to create an instance variable that's only visible inside the class?

Comment: I'm not sure. I copied straight from a tutorial example.

Comment: @user1182000 Those are not global variables, they are [class variables](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_classes.html#classvariables).

Comment: @user1182000 The `@@` prefix does not create a global variable, it creates a class variable. Global variables start with `$`.

Comment: Traditional, Java-like singletons don't make any sense in Ruby. Since the classes themselves are objects, they can serve as the singleton instance. Class methods are actually instance methods where ‘self‘ is the class instance. You can even use instance variables, which are not shared within the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, except for the last line. Perhaps you meant:

```
p Logger.create.object_id
```

Comment: @stanigator It [prints the value](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p).

Comment: So I don't have to just use puts or print to print the value?

Comment: @stanigator Read the docs, or experiment, or read a tutorial; each serves its own purpose.

Comment: Sorry for the preemptive follow-up question.